# libibverbs.so.1 missing when compiling Fortran code using OpenMPI

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I had a Fortran code that uses OpenMPI for parallel computing. When I ran my code two weeks ago, things went smoothly. But today I had this weird error:

```
mpif90 ./nrutil.f90 ./matrix.f90 ./probability.f90 ./random.f90 ./ardiscret.f90 
./trans_ind_sub.f90 ./globvar.f90 ./interpolpr.f90 ./viterch.f90 ./viterpr.f90 
./bisearch.f90 ./simulate.f90 ./statistics.f90   ./moment.f90 ./main.f90    
-g -o output.out  
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libibverbs.so.1, needed by /home/wenya/.openmpi/lib/libmpi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/wenya/.openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to  `ibv_read_sysfs_file@IBVERBS_1.0'
/home/wenya/.openmpi/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to  `ibv_register_driver@IBVERBS_1.1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'output' failed
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile:

```
#Compiler
fc = mpif90
#Compiler flags
FCFLAGS= -fcheck=all

SRCS= ./nrutil.f90  \
    ./matrix.f90 \
    ./probability.f90 \
    ./random.f90 \
    ./ardiscret.f90  \
    ./trans_ind_sub.f90 \
    ./globvar.f90 \
    ./interpolpr.f90 \
    ./viterch.f90\
    ./viterpr.f90 \
    ./bisearch.f90\
    ./simulate.f90 \
    ./statistics.f90 \
    ./moment.f90 \
    ./main.f90 \
output:
    $(fc) $(SRCS) -g -o output.out $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
debug:
    $(fc) $(SRCS) -g -o debug.exe
clean:
    rm -rf *.mod *.o *.il *~ \#* PI*

run:
   mpirun -np 8 ./output.out
```

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2; GNU Fortran: 5.4.0. I wonder if there is anything wrong with the OpenMPI installation. When I type `ompi_info` to get OpenMPI version number, I get

```
ompi_info: error while loading shared libraries: libibverbs.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is somehow goofy, as the program ran smoothly two weeks ago. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't be surprised nobody replied to your question. Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Comment: This looks like some mess in the system configuration. How do you load your modules? Was there any update of the software recently?

Comment: The InfiniBand verbs API library has gone missing. Have there been any changes to the environment, e.g., system upgrades, etc.?

Comment: @VladimirF I'm not sure what do you mean by modules.. The OS was recently reinstalled two weeks ago. But the program once ran successfully  after the reinstallation. There has been no updates after that.

Comment: @HristoIliev No updates since the program ran smoothly two weeks ago. How can I fix the missing library?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libibverbs` or rebuild Open MPI without InfiniBand support.

Comment: @HristoIliev It says unable to locate package libibverbs ..

Comment: Use `apt-cache search libibverbs` to search for the correct package. I haven't used Ubuntu in quite some time.

Comment: Thanks, @HristoIliev. The package is renamed into libibverbs1. After installing it, the program can run now.